# How to toggle two icons in v-for list item in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a list of items and icons which I want to toggle. How should I do that? Right now my click affects all of the items.

```
<ion-item
        v-for="course in courses"
        :key="course.id">
  <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">{{ course.name }}</ion-label>
  <span @click="toggleIcons">
    <ion-icon v-if="isSelected" :icon="ellipseOutline" slot="end"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon v-else :icon="checkmarkCircleOutline" slot="end"></ion-icon>
  </span>
</ion-item>


///


data() {
    return {
        isSelected: false,
        }
    },
methods: {
    toggleIcons(){
        this.isSelected = !this.isSelected
    }
}
```

Comment: Each entry in `courses` needs to store the `isSelected` state individually.

Comment: @Terry is there some other way how to do it? cause I cant change anything about courses

Comment: Another way is simply to create a new component to handle on a per item basis, then it can store the `isSelected` state on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following snipet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
      return {
        courses: [{id:1, name: 'aaa'}, {id:2, name: 'bbb'},{id:3, name: 'ccc'}],
        isSelected:  null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      toggleIcons(id){
        this.isSelected === id ? this.isSelected=null : this.isSelected = id
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="course in courses" :key="course.id">
    <label class="ion-text-wrap">{{ course.name }}</label>
    <button @click="toggleIcons(course.id)">
    click
      <div v-if="isSelected === course.id " slot="end">1</div>
      <div v-if="isSelected !== course.id " slot="end">2</div>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and if i need one icon to be shown from the beginning?

Comment: @Smna hey mate, check now pls, I update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is have a data property to keep the index(or the `course.id` in your case) of the "toggled" button

And then `@click` set the `course.id` of the clicked item to the data property, after that you can match the data property to the `course.id` and show your icon

Check the example below

*Data Property*

```
  data() {
    return {
      selectedCourseId: null,
    }
  },
```

*Method to set (or you can set it inline)*

```
  methods: {
    setSelectedCourseId(id) {
      this.selectedCourseId = id
    },
  }
```

*Template*

```
<ion-item v-for="course in courses" :key="course.id">
  <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">{{ course.name }}</ion-label>
  <span @click="toggleIcons">
    <ion-icon v-if="selectedCourseId === course.id" :icon="ellipseOutline" slot="end"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon v-else :icon="checkmarkCircleOutline" slot="end"></ion-icon>
  </span>
</ion-item>
```